# How can I zebra-format rows in Excel 2010 automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, format

I've got a long list of data (export from MySQL) that I want to print out to tick each row after I've done stuff with it. Is there an easy way in Excel 2010 on Windows to make the table zebra-backgrounded for better readability? I've found some solutions that use conditional formatting, but that doesn't seem to work in Excel 2010. Also, my Excel is in German and the English formula commands do not work.

Comment: Why not just use **Format as Table** from the **Home** tab and select a design with alternating colors? Or am I misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I didn't know about it. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fastest way I have found is to select your data and click the `Format as Table` button on the Home Ribbon. Choose the style you want.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you need a better control over your style, and all you need is just a zebra, then do this:

1. Select the rows you want to format.
2. On the Home tab, in the Styles group, click the arrow next to Conditional Formatting, and then click New Rule.
3. In the New Formatting Rule dialog box, under Select a Rule Type, click Use a formula to determine which cells to format.
4. In the Format values where this formula is true box, enter =MOD(ROW(),2)=0
5. Click Format, choose your formatting, and apply it.

Full instructions are here: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Apply-shading-to-alternate-rows-in-a-worksheet-9e77c551-0bcf-4515-9497-fdbf724de9be

I can only guess in German version of Excel: MOD(ROW(),2) will be REST(ZEILE(),2)

For English-German translation use this: http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/index.php?page=english-german.html

Comment: The correct German Excel formula is REST(ZEILE();2) . I tried to edit, but the change was rejected as being too short ... duh . Short syntax errors really exist!

Comment: I love this way!